# systemd-run memory limit is not shown in /proc/meminfo, is there another way?

Tags: linux, memory, systemd

I'm trying to write a program that waits when it sees it's memory is becoming full. It finds out what the current available memory is using `/proc/meminfo`. Now I'm trying to test it by running `systemd-run --scope -p MemoryMax=100M -p MemorySwapMax=0` but `/proc/meminfo` is still returning the old values (which I kind of get why it does that).
Is there another place or way I can retrieve the available memory that does look at the limits set by `systemd-run`?.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Systemd uses cgroups.

```
$ systemd-run -P --user -p MemoryMax=10240000 -p MemorySwapMax=0 bash -c 'd=/sys/fs/cgroup/$(cut -d: -f3 /proc/self/cgroup); tail $d/memory{.swap,}.max'
Running as unit: run-u923.service
==> /sys/fs/cgroup//user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/run-u923.service/memory.swap.max <==
0

==> /sys/fs/cgroup//user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/run-u923.service/memory.max <==
10240000
```